# FileHelpers - Creating a field object

Tags: c#, csv, dynamic, filehelpers

I am trying to dynamically add field properties to a record class that I am also building dynamically using FileHelpers.Dynamic.DelimitedClassBuilder.  I have no issues creating the class object and I currently add a field using the AddField(String) method.

As my apps grows I now have a need to declare specific field properties in various situations.  So in the same sense I wanted to use FileHelpers.Dynamic.DelimitedFieldBuilder to create a field object and then pass that to my DelimitedClassBuilder object using the method AddField(DelimitedFieldBuilder).

However I am unable to instantiate a new object using FileHelpers.Dynamic.DelimitedFieldBuilder.  When I issue the following code I get an error stating that DelimitedFieldBuilder does not contain a constructor that takes two arguments.

```
FileHelpers.Dynamic.DelimitedFieldBuilder fb = new FileHelpers.Dynamic.DelimitedFieldBuilder("ClassName", "Type");
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_Dynamic_DelimitedFieldBuilder.htm) it appears that this class does only have properties associated with it, so I am kind of stuck on how to actually implement this.  It seems like it should be fairly easy but I cant seem to figure it out.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with that functionality of file helpers; however, in the vast majority of functions/methods across .NET there is usually a way to assign properties after the class is instantiated.

Try something like this:

```
FileHelpers.Dynamic.DelimitedFieldBuilder fb = new FileHelpers.Dynamic.DelimitedFieldBuilder();
fb.Whatever = "ClassName";
fb.otherwhatever = "Type";
```

Just a stab. I have no idea if it will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

The constructors of [`DelimitedFieldBuilder`](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/master/FileHelpers/Dynamic/DelimitedFieldBuilder.cs) are `internal` so you'll run into difficulty with your approach. However `AddField(String)` returns a `DelimitedFieldBuilder`, so you might be able to use that.

It might be easier to make your own class `MyFieldBuilder` which calls the standard `AddField(String)`.